# Git autocompletion is not working with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, auto-complete

Here is my setup:

```
brew install git bash-completion
Warning: git-2.1.3 already installed
Warning: bash-completion-1.3 already installed
```

In .bash_profile:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

But I still don't have autocompletion for git commands. (I used macports before, but completely removed it because I couldn't get git commands to autocomplete no matter what I tried.)

I am on OSX 10.10

Answer (score 9):

For Yosemite, after I upgraded to git 2.1.3 with homebrew, this worked in my `.profile` file (`.bash_profile` or similar would work, too):

```
# git tab completion (homebrew)
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi
```

I used to have `git-prompt.sh` there, but changing it to `git-completion.bash` worked for me.  ymmv.

Answer (score 3):

Try download directly in your home directory:

```
curl -O https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
mv git-completion.bash .git-completion.bash
```

Then in your `.bash_profile` add the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
    . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Comment: Did this `wget  https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash && source git-completion.bash`, no luck yet.

Comment: @qed, that + answer's .bash_profile worked for me.

Comment: Even `. ~/.git-completion.bash` directly in the shell does not work. No error message either.

Comment: The link above is a redirect, so we need to follow it: `curl -L https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash > .git-completion.bash`

Answer (score 1):

On my system (10.10.5), I fixed this by creating a symlink in /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/ to the bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash in the GIT directory. In my case:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
ln -s ../../Cellar/git/2.7.2/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash git-completion.bash
```

be sure to checkout your installed version of git and replace 2.7.2 with your version.

Comment: I already have that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Along with the other answers, doing this as well worked for me. Thanks!