# Git auto-completion not working on Mac OSX 10.11.5 El Capitan

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, homebrew, git

I have tried the examples found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154701/git-autocompletion-is-not-working-with-homebrew) to get Git auto-completion working on El Capitan, however none of the examples work for me.

I installed `bash-completion` with Homebrew (`brew install bash-completion`).

This is my `~/.bash_profile` currently (as you can see, i've tried a few things):

```
CRMPiccosMacBook:etc crmpicco$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
alias ll='ls -lG'
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"

#if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
#   . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
#fi

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi

#source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
#GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
#export PS1='[\u@mbp \w$(__git_ps1)]\$ '
```

So, if I go into my directory with the cloned Git repo and type `git checkout m` and hit [TAB] I get nothing (when expecting `master` to be pre-filled).

When I run a `source` on it, it doesn't exist - however it's installed.

```
CRMPiccos-MacBook:signup crmpicco$ brew install bash-completion
Warning: bash-completion-1.3_1 already installed
CRMPiccos-MacBook:signup crmpicco$ source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
-bash: /etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Tony Williams' answer here looks solid and this *used* to work for me on my Mac, I believe. Not sure when or why it stopped working on my Mac and now Tony's advice also didn't fix it for me. However, Michael Durrant's advice [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875/git-auto-complete-for-branches-at-the-command-line) did!

Answer (score 28):

You are confusing the basic bash completion with the add on required for completing git commands.

The `git` that is installed by Apple lacks the required `git-completion.bash` file so you need to install the full git. You can do this easily with homebrew -`brew install git` will do the job.

Once you've done that then uncomment your top three lines :-

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Now `source ~/.bash_profile` and it should work fine.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, Tony, but it still does not work

Comment: The steps you need are :- (1) Install `bash-completion` using homebrew (2) install `git` using homebrew. (3) add the lines above to your `.bash_profile`. Now open a new Terminal window and you should find git completion working.

Comment: Installing git with `brew install git` solved my problem. Thanks @TonyWilliams

Comment: I found with Homebrew `git version 2.15.0` the bash completion script path is slightly different, so `\`brew --prefix\`/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`

Comment: In my case, git version: `2.18.0`, the file was in `$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`

Comment: I had to install brew install `git bash-completion` then adding 
`if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi`

to bash_profile.

Answer (score 11):

As a note for users, like me, who already updated to macOS Catalina, which deprecated `bash`, yet ended up at this answer as a top result...

For macOS Catalina+, which uses `zsh`, there are a few other requirements. Download both scripts:

```
curl -o git-completion.bash https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
curl -o _git https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
```

Then update your `~/.zshrc` with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash
fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)

autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this was downvoted when it is both correct and relevant to Catalina, which uses ``zsh``.

Comment: Where these files are supposed to be stored?

Comment: The title of this question refers to Catalina, but a careful reader will note that the detail in the question refers to `bash`. Therefore, a `zsh` answer misses the question's point.

Comment: Getting `not found: __git_aliased_command` when trying branch name autocomplete :/ basic commands autocomplete, e.g. for `checkout` works though.

Answer (score 8):

**Enable Git Tab Autocomplete for Zsh**

New Macs use the Zsh shell by default. If you’re using Zsh, add the following line to the ~/.zshrc file and restart your Terminal application:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

Alternatively, you can run the following two commands in your Terminal application to add the necessary line to the .zshrc file and restart your shell.

```
echo 'autoload -Uz compinit && compinit' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Git tab autocomplete is now enabled on your Mac.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and the first result to appear on Google :) .. thanks man

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55886/291502) I solved it using these commands

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

Then I edited the file by running `vi ~/.zshrc` and added following part to it

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Then I did run `source ~/.zshrc` then git suggestions started working properly.

Comment: The title of this question refers to Catalina, but a careful reader will note that the detail in the question refers to bash. Therefore, a zsh answer misses the question's point.

Comment: This results in `ERROR: this script is obsolete, please see git-completion.zsh`

Answer (score 1):

For people using bash 5, you can install the homebrew package [`bash-completion@2`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash-completion@2) and add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`.

```sh
[[ -r "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "$(brew --prefix)/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

Comment: How does this improve on answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245324/237

Comment: The syntax for configuration with the newer bash completion is different than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on Sierra. Found [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/docker-mac-bash-completion/).

After installing `bash-completion` and adding the snippet to your `.bash_profile`:

```
cd /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d  
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker.bash-completion  
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-machine.bash-completion  
ln -s /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/docker-compose.bash-completion
```